How can I solve this issue on android studio?
This is how my build, execution and deployment settings look like and i don't know how to correct this error

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not open settings generic class cache for settings file '/Users/user/Desktop/flutter_projects/mi_card_flutter/android/settings.gradle' (/Users/user/.gradle/caches/7.0.2/scripts/1445wdyck9xmnqxfk9atcnkpf).
> BUG! exception in phase 'semantic analysis' in source unit '_BuildScript_' Unsupported class file major version 65

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.


gradle home general location is Users/your_user_name/.gradle some thing like this https://resources.jetbrains.com/help/img/idea/2024.2/gradle_settings_use_gradle_from.png . Update it and invalidate cache and restart.

I think Android Studio LadyBug its breaking things, here I found a workaround for your issue:Unsupported class file major version 65 with Java 21 "workaround"
basically you have to do the following:
Update /android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties:
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-8.4-all.zip

Update /android/settings.gradle:
plugins {
    id "com.android.application" version "8.3.2" apply false
}

